# unable to do cd got file not found in PATH

Tags: linux, cd-command

```
Error: process caused \"exec: \\\"cd\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"}

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

From where `cd` will execute?

Comment: Please read the [How to ask a good question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) article.  Is this for Docker by any chance? There are no clues in your question.

Comment: This ^^^ and to make it abundantly clear: Make your question full of clues for us to solve it. Otherwise we'll vote to close it.

Comment: Yes, it's a docker container.

Comment: @garethTheRed When i run sh -c "cd mydir" got following error: syntax error: unterminated quoted string

Answer (score 3):

`cd` is a not an executable command on the file system ([though POSIX compliant systems have one](/q/50058)), it's an internal builtin command of a shell to change its own current working directory.

A process cannot execute a command in a child process to change its own current working directory as the current working directory is a property of each process.

Whatever language you're using to try and execute that `cd` command will have its own interface to change the current working directory.

For instance, instead of:

```
spawn_cmd("cd", "/some/dir");
```

Or whatever command you use to execute a command, in C, use:

```
chdir("/some/dir")
```

Where `chdir()` is the libc interface to the `chdir` system call.

Note that, if in C, you wrote:

```
system("cd /some/dir");
```

That would *not* output an error, because that would actually be doing something like:

```
spawn_cmd("sh", "-c", "cd /some/dir");
```

that is, run a *shell* in a child process to evaluate that `cd /some/dir` shell code, upon which the shell would invoke its builtin `cd` command to change its own current working directory (but again, not the current working directory of the parent process that spawning a process to execute that command).

However, you could do:

```
system("cd /some/dir && exec some-other-command");
```

same as:

```
spawn_cmd("sh", "-c", "cd /some/dir && exec some-other-command");
```

or for arbitrary directory and command to avoid running the risk of them being interpreted as shell code:

```
spawn_cmd("sh", "-c",
          "unset -v CDPATH;"
          "cd -P -- \"$1\" || exit;"
          "shift;"
          "exec \"$@\"", "sh", "/some/dir", "some-other-command");
```

Then, that child process would execute `sh` which would change its working directory and then execute that `some-other-command` in the same process, so with that new working directory.

Comment: This is a docker container, run command I am executing "cd" command and got PATH error, later I tried to run sh -c "cd mydir got  syntax error: unterminated quoted string

Comment: @user60679, and what are you trying to achieve with that? What's the point of running a `sh` command in that container that changes its current directory and then exits? If you want to run another command with that new current working directory, run `sh -c "cd mydir && exec that-other-command"` or `perl -e 'chdir("mydir"); exec("that-other-command")'`, that is you don't have to use a shell to change the cwd, though a shell would be the most obvious command to do that (but the shell's `cd` has more issues in general than `perl`'s `chdir()`, hence the CDPATH/-P/-- in my answer).

Comment: yes i am running, sh -c " cd mydir && terraform plan" still same error.

Comment: @user60679, check the manual of whatever tool you're entering that command line in to check what syntax it recognises. In the end, you want to run the `sh` command with 3 arguments: `sh`, `-c` and `cd mydir && terraform plan`. It may be that it doesn't recognise `"` as a quoting operator and you need to enter it as `sh -c cd\ mydir&&terraform\ plan` or maybe on the contrary that you need to escape those `"` as in `sh -c \"cd mydir && terraform plan\"`...